# Sequelize ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR Unknown column 'id' in 'field list

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am getting the error message displayed below when I try to make a Users model.

> code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
>       errno: 1054,
>       sqlState: '42S22',
>       sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'",
>       sql: 'SELECT `id`, `beta`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS ' +
>         '`User`;'

Here is my `Users.js` file:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const models = require("../config/config");

const Users = models.define("User", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    }, beta: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: false
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(25),
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(25),
        allowNull: false
    }
});

module.exports = User;
```

I have tried to run this with and without the id property, because I know that Sequelize will generate its own primary key if a PK is not specified, but neither attempts worked. I am using MySQL as the config dialect.

Comment: Maybe you're not "syncing" your database schema with your model definition in your .js file. Did you double-check the schema generated in your MySQL table?

Comment: I think everything is good.. The most important thing to have the .sync() right? Which belongs in the entry point of the project (app/server/index.js)?

Comment: Do you use migrations to create the table?